# Complete metric for the topology of compact convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

This question has been posed in multiple forms on here, but there is always one  bit of information lacking.
Suppose one considers the space $C$ of continuous functions $f:\mathopen [ 0,+\infty \mathclose [ \rightarrow Y$ where $Y$ is a complete metric space with metric $\rho \leqslant 1$. Define $d_n(f,g)=\sup \left \{\rho(f(x),g(x))| \  x\in \mathopen [ 0,n\mathclose ] \right \}$ for $f,g \in C$, then set $d\left ( f,g \right )= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {2^{-n}}d_n\left ( f,g \right )$. One proves: $d$ is a metric on $C$ that induces the topology of compact convergence. However, why is $d$ complete? Supposedly, this is a trivial matter - it never gets explained - but I don't see why. If $\left ( f_k\right )$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C$ for the metric $d$, apparently, then one should prove that the sequence converges pointwise (that's easy enough) but what next?

Comment: The convergence to the pointwise limit is in fact uniform on all intervals. Therefore, the limit is continuous and convergence happen with respect to $d$.

Comment: It's best not to use $n$ as both the index of metrics and the index of functions. These are different indices.

Answer (score 4):

First note that 
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} d(f_k, f) = 0 \iff
\forall n \ \lim_{k\to\infty} d_n(f_k, f) = 0 \tag1
$$ 
If $(f_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d$, then by (1) their  restrictions to $[0, n]$ form a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d_n$. Since $C[0, n]$ is complete ([reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83830/how-to-show-that-c-c0-1-is-a-banach-space)), we have $g_n\in C[0, n]$ such that $f_k\to g_n$ uniformly on $[0, n]$.

Next, observe that the functions $g_n$ are such that the restriction of $g_n$ to $[0, m]$ with $m<n$ is exactly $g_m$. (This follows from the uniqueness of pointwise limits.) Thus, we can define
$$
g(x) = g_n(x)  \quad \text{where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is any such that $n\ge x$}
$$
which is a continuous function because each $g_n$ is continuous.
Finally, $d(f_k, g)\to 0$ by (1).